# Redirecting to Origin host name App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

The problem is when I add a custom domain the custom domain was not working but when i access with default domain I can access app service.

Once the domain is up when I test the browser it redirects to the origin host name.
I tired to delete the origin host header but doesn't work its giving me a 404 error.
What am I missing in my configuration?

Comment: Describe "the custom domain was not working"

Answer (score 0):

- I have added a custom domain to azure front door using below steps.

[image]

- Click on **review+create**.
- We have to config some setting after deploying the azure front door.
- GOTO custom domain as below.

[image]

[image]

- In the DNS Zone select DNS name and set the Azure front door endpoint as below.

[image]

[image]

- when I click on the custom domain, I can access the web app using front door custom domain.

[image]

[image]